# Join 2 tables on column x based on max value of column y in second table

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, max

I have read some posts here. Using this post ([Select value A from the same record as max( value B) and then join with another table on value C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45277738/select-value-a-from-the-same-record-as-max-value-b-and-then-join-with-another)) I have started my query but it does not work. Are nested SELECT queries even allowed in Access?

collar

```
_______________________
|hole_id|max_depth|...|
|  1    |  340    |   |
|  2    |  400    |   |
|  3    |  250    |   |
```

assay

```
______________________
|hole_id|depth_to|...|
|  1    |  58    |   |
|  1    |  62    |   |
|  1    |  69    |   |
|  2    |  102   |   |
|  2    |  110   |   |
|  3    |  20    |   |
|  3    |  25    |   |
```

I need to return

```
________________________________
|hole_id|max_depth|depth_to|...|
|  1    |  340    |  69    |   |
|  2    |  400    |  110   |   |
|  3    |  250    |  25    |   |
```

-

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.hole_id, A.max_depth, B.depth_from, B.depth_to
FROM collar A
LEFT JOIN assay B
ON A.hole_id = B.hole_id
WHERE A.hole_id = (
     SELECT max(C.depth_to)
     FROM assay C
     WHERE C.hole_id = A.hole_id
     )
WHERE A.max_depth > B.depth_to AND A.section="BLK" AND A.holetype="Exploration"
;
```

Comment: I should mention that I have all sorts of other fields there but I don't think they are relevant to the logic.

Answer (score 1):

Just join the two tables, return the maximum depth_to and group the rest.  No need to nest queries in this case.

```
SELECT      assay.hole_id
            , max_depth
            , MAX(depth_to) AS max_depth_to
FROM        assay LEFT JOIN collar ON assay.hole_id = collar.hole_id
GROUP BY    assay.hole_id, max_depth
ORDER BY    assay.hole_id
```

Also no need to fully qualify each field name if it's unique to one table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT collar.hole_id, collar.max_depth, (select max(depth_to) from assay where assay.hole_id=collar.hole_id) AS depth_to
FROM collar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, nested `SELECT` queries can be done in Access.  Here's one that may give you what you're looking for:

```
SELECT
    A.hole_id, 
    A.max_depth, 
    B.depth_from, 
    B.depth_to
FROM 
    collar A
LEFT JOIN 
    (select B.*
    from assay B
        inner join (
            select hole_id, max(depth_to) as max_depth
            from assay
            group by hole_id
            ) BD on BD.hole_id=B.hole_id and BD.max_depth=B.depth_to
     ) as BM on BM.hole_id=A.hole_id
WHERE 
    A.section="BLK" AND A.holetype="Exploration"
;
```